# Не могу закрыть уведомление свайпом вправо. Как это сделать?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
     override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    if (!isNotificationShown()) {
            startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())

        LocationResult.extractResult(intent)?.let { locationResult ->
            locationResult.locations[0]?.let { location ->
                firebaseUserRepository.updateUserLocation(location)
            }
        }
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }

 private fun getNotification(): Notification {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                val channel =
                    NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
            val notificationIntent = Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity::class.java)
            return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.service_location_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_location_message))
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(getString(R.string.service_location_message))
                )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_itransition)
                .setTimeoutAfter(2000)
                .build()
}
```

Comment: `.setOngoing(false);`

Comment: это не работает

Comment: `.setTimeoutAfter(2000)` попробуй это убрать и поставить `.setOngoing(false);`

Comment: это тож не работает. В начале оно вызывается, и пропадает, но в общем списке уведомлений оно есть и его невозможно скрыть. Я кстати еще больше кода добавил для большего понимания кода)

Comment: Уведомление для "Foreground Service" удалить нельзя - это требование системы.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а как можно исправить ошибку?

Comment: Какую ошибку? Повторяю ещё раз - это требование системы, приложение не должно работать в "тихушку". И по-хорошему должно дать юзеру возможность управлять работающей службой через это самое уведомление, или как минимум, видеть статус задачи.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы уведомление можно было скрыть свайпом вправо?

Comment: То, что передано в `startForeground()` можно удалить, скрыть и как бы ещё вы это не назвали, только после вызова `stopForeground`. Поведение обычного уведомления, которое выводится через `NotificationManager.notify()`, вы можете настроить как угодно.